# How to get all the parent classes of a derived class in C# Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, interface

It is weird that I was not able to find a similar question but this is what actually I want, finding all the parent classes of a derived class.

I tested a code with a hope that it works for me :

```
void WriteInterfaces()
{
    var derivedClass = new DerivedClass();
    var type = derivedClass.GetType();
    var interfaces = type.FindInterfaces((objectType, criteria) =>
                                            objectType.Name == criteria.ToString(),"BaseClass");

    foreach(var face in interfaces)
    {
        face.Name.Dump();
    }
}

interface BaseInterface
{}

class BaseClass : BaseInterface {}

class BaseClass2 : BaseClass {}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass2{}
```

Basically, here my main intention is to check if a derived class somehow inherits a base class somewhere in its base hierarchy.

However, this code returns null and works only with interfaces.

Comment: Your requirement is a bit strange (maybe I misunderstand).. but a derived class will always inherit a base class that is somewhere in it's hierarchy.. thats why its "derived"..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you don't *actually* need all the other types - you just need [`Type.IsSubclassOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.issubclassof.aspx) or [`Type.IsAssignableFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx). However, getting all the type in the hierarchy is easy using [`Type.BaseType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.basetype.aspx):

```
public static IEnumerable<Type> GetClassHierarchy(Type type)
{
    while (type != null)
    {
        yield return type;
        type = type.BaseType;
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess that "sweet, question-laden embrace" was too much for you :P

Comment: OK it makes sense now. Thanks for the answer. Marked as the answer.